# Image registration between points and its boundary

Tags: image-processing, image-registration

I have an image of a tissue (left) and XY-coordinates of the points within it (right).

[image: Image of a tissue (left) and points within it]

I want to get them to same reference coordinates so that I can get the XY-coordinates of the boundaries of the tissue (that is the coordinate system of the points should match the coordinate system of the tissue). I *don't* want to segment the points since I want to use their already existing coordinate representation. How do I get the XY-coordinates of the tissue (and hence its boundaries) matching the points? Thanks.

Comment: For example, you can find the center of mass of the convex hull for both a set of points and a picture of the tissue.

Comment: It's a good start I think. The coordinates of the center may not match though. But it is likely to be close. Let me see...